Optimizing Reload Time for Qlik view Script with RIGHT JOIN
I'm working on a Qlik Sense script that integrates opening stock data from an as_of_balance table into a sales_history table. The goal is to ensure that every record in sales_history is enriched with the corresponding opening_stock from as_of_balance, even if there are no matching transactions for some records. Here's the critical part of my script:
CALL as_of_balance

LOAD
    as_of_key,
    product_key,
    business_unit_key,
    date
RESIDENT $(table_name);

// Perform a RIGHT JOIN with the as_of_balance table
RIGHT JOIN ($(table_name))
LOAD
    as_of_key,
    product_key,
    business_unit_key,
    opening_stock
RESIDENT as_of_balance;

// Clean up
DROP TABLE as_of_balance;
The Problem:
This script works as intended, but the reload time is excessively long, which impacts performance. I believe the RIGHT JOIN operation, combined with the large size of the as_of_balance and $(table_name) tables, is the primary cause of the delay. The as_of_balance table is quite large, and I need to ensure that all relevant opening_stock data is matched with the sales_history data without unnecessary processing overhead.
What I’ve Tried:
Filtering Data: I attempted to filter data from as_of_balance to reduce the size before the join, but this did not significantly impact reload time.
Optimizing Join Logic: I considered alternatives like LEFT JOIN and using mapping tables but encountered challenges in ensuring that all data from $(table_name) is retained while still adding the correct opening_stock.
Optimizing the Script: How can I adjust this script to reduce the reload time without losing the integrity of the data? Specifically, how can I optimize the RIGHT JOIN or consider alternative methods that might perform better in Qlik Sense?
Best Practices: Are there best practices for handling such join operations in Qlik, especially when dealing with large datasets like mine?
Incremental Loading: Would an incremental loading strategy help here, and if so, how might that be implemented in this context?
The $(table_name) contains sales history data, and I need to ensure that all dates and product combinations are preserved in the final output.
The as_of_balance table only has fiscal year dates, which are adjusted and aligned with the sales history dates in the script.
Any insights or suggestions to optimize this part of my Qlik script would be greatly appreciated!
